# Why does hyphenation change if heading is at top of page

Tags: titlesec, hyphenation

Sorry for not able to provide a MWE. At the moment I need some ideas to where to look for this strange behaviour.

In a document, a section is hyphenated even if it is more space in the line. See how the title of section 4 is longer!

[image]

A more strange behaviour is that if the header is not at the top fo the page, the hyphenation doesn't occur!

[image]

If I increase the `textwidth` just by 1.2 cm; the hyphenation doesn't occur either.

Any idea where can I start looking? The headings are defined using the `titlesec` package

```
%%% Definition standar hedings using titlesec
% \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
% {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubparagraph}{1em}{}
% \titlespacing*{\chapter}
% {0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1em}
\titlespacing*{\subparagraph} {\parindent}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1em}
```

Comment: Make a minimal example.

Comment: I'd experiment with »blindtext« and the titlesec package and your definitions in an MWE. Probably better to have the MWE in portuguese. Consider switching to a KOMA-script class and thus to avoid titlesec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process of writing the MWE show that the problem was a previous `wrapfig` environment. There too many line defined for the wrapped figure, that run into the heading.